# Repeatedly calling JavaScript function without getting a stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**So a little background on what I am trying to do:**
I am trying to create a real time chat application which uses ajax to repeatedly check for new messages on the server.
The difference here is I am using the [`long-polling`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) technique which works like this:

1. Java-Script sends an request to the server using ajax
2. If the server has a new message, it responds back with the new message
3. If the server doesn't have a new message, it simply doesn't return anything and the request remains alive (still connected to the server waiting for a response)
4. Once the server gets a new message, it immediately responds with the new message to the request which was on hold/waiting for a response

---

## What I am trying to do

I am confused on how to write the client-sided scipt.
As per the description above, the script should

1. Create a request
2. On `receiving content`, execute a function (update chat box) **and then send request again**
3. On `timeout`, simply send a request again and simply wait for a response till timeout

---

## What I have attempted

So this is my script when in the main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getMsg();
    });

    function getMsg() {
        var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

        $.ajax({
            url: "get_message.php?lastupdate=" + time,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 15000, //15 second timeout
            success: function(response) {
                $('#chatBox').append("> " + response + "<br/>");
                getMsg();
            },
            error: function(x, t, m) {
                getMsg();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

---

## The problem

As you see here, on `error` and `success` I am calling the `getMsg()` function from the `getMsg()` function its self. Dont I run the risk of getting a stackoverflow? I mean of course this is going to be almost impossible since that would need a huge number of recursions but still it feels like a bad programming method...
Is there an alternative way to do this where the script:

1. Creates a request
2. On Receiving content, execute a function (update chat box) **and then send request again**
3. On Time Out, simply restart function again

Thanks for spending your time to read this!

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a stack overflow because the outer `getMsg` function returns after the ajax request is _fired_; it doesn't stay running while the ajax request is in flight.

Comment: You may want to add a delay or some kind of limit to your error callback, especially if your Ajax call fails due to something other than a timeout. Consider what would happen if your client disconnected from the Internet, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Don't I run the risk of getting a stack overflow?

### Short answer:

No.

### Long answer:

When you call `$.ajax`, the current instance of `getMsg` doesn't *wait* for the AJAX request to be complete. It just binds all the event handlers that you have and then says *"alright, I'm done"*:

```
function getMsg() {
    var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

    $.ajax({
        // all your options
    });

    // alright, I'm done
}
```

So it returns.

**Why?**, you ask. Because the "A" in AJAX stands for [asynchronous](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/). This means that when you initiate an AJAX request, everything else can *move on.*

By the time that you call `getMsg` in your handlers, it's a *new* instance that is **not** recursive. There is never more than one `getMsg` running. There's no recursion. No stack overflow. No problem.

Comment: It seems that if `getMsg` took parameters, you could end up using larger and larger amounts of stack space to accommodate the closure variables. Does that sound correct?

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot To some point, yes. On the other hand, by the time that you call the new `getMsg`, the old scope no longer has any active references, so the garbage collection will get rid of the closure from the stack.

Comment: True, and you'd have to do some *really* stupid parameter passing for that to increase with each call.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on why there is no risk of an SO! Makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery also supports the [always property](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) on promises.  So to be more succinct you could do the getMsg() call in the always block

```
.always(getMsg);
```

You don't have to worry about recursion because it only fires after it completes.

Answer (score 1):

No SO danger in such code

Just put getMsg() to 'complete' property ( to have one entire point to recall function ) like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getMsg();
    });

    function getMsg() {
        var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

        $.ajax({
            url: "get_message.php?lastupdate=" + time,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 15000, //15 second timeout
            success: function(response) {
                $('#chatBox').append("> " + response + "<br/>");
            },
            complete: getMsg // code will be executed on success/error
        });
    }
</script>
```

And you must keep in mind - if response will come fast - you will get many request - so maybe limit period as 15 seconds min like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getMsg();
    });

    function getMsg() {
        var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

        $.ajax({
            url: "get_message.php?lastupdate=" + time,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 15000, //15 second timeout
            success: function(response) {
                $('#chatBox').append("> " + response + "<br/>");
            },
            complete: function(){
                setTimeout(getMsg, 15000); // call with delay
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I really like the method of calling the function on `complete` didn't notice that! +1

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMsg() {

    var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    var settings = {
        url: "get_message.php?lastupdate=" + time,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 15000, //15 second timeout
    };

    var req = $.ajax(settings);

    req.done(function(msg){$('#chatBox').append("> " + response + "<br/>");});

    req.fail(function(msg){$('#chatBox').append("> Network offline<br/>");});

    req.complete(getMsg); //runs after error/and success
}
```